# Unable to select the sim in this popup

Tags: android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YLwD.jpg

Set the always ask option for calls in phone settings. Try to making the call in my own app. This sim selection popup was came but unable to select the sim(disabled). Also passing the particular sim for call but also same issue.

Need to make a call through my app with the sim selection. Other native dialer's are working fine. Only google phone app blocking the sim selection

Comment: Hey, I'm facing the same issue. Have you figured it out? Also on what version of Android and what phone model is this happening?

Comment: Yes. I'm found the solution. This is not a android version and model wise issue. I'm facing the issue in phone sim account fetching. After change the sim account fetching process to google dialer sim selection popup not showing @Devenom

Comment: Oh ok. What is the solution?